# next-auth.js with next.js middleware redirects to sign-in page after successful sign-in

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I use next-auth.js with Google as my login provider and Django as my backend. To protect pages in next.js, I am trying to integrate next-auth.js with next.js middleware. [Reference link](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware)

The issue I have is when the user is logged out, the middleware correctly routes to the login page. But after successful login, the user is redirected to the login page again. What am I missing?

middleware.js

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"

export const config = { matcher: ["/jobs/:path*", "/accounts/:path*", "/profile/:path*", "/uploads/:path*"] }
```

/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth.js]

```
import axios from "axios";
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { isJwtExpired } from "../../../constants/Utils";

 async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE + "/api/auth/token/refresh/", {
      refresh: token.refreshToken
    });

    const { access, refresh } = response.data;
    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: access,
      refreshToken: refresh,
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    
    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshTokenError"
    }
  }
}

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Google({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorization: {
          params: {
            access_type: "offline",
            response_type: "code",
            scope:'openid profile email'
          }
        }
      }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account}) {
      // Initial sign in
      if (account && user) {

        if (account.provider === "google") {
          const { access_token: accessToken } = account;
          
          try {
            // make a GET request to the DRF backend
            const response = await axios.get(
              process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE + "/api/auth/register-by-token/google-oauth2/",
                {
                  params: 
                  {
                    access_token: accessToken
                  }
                }
            );
      
            const { access, refresh } = response.data;
            token = {
              ...token,
              accessToken: access,
              refreshToken: refresh,
            };
            return token
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)

            return {
              ...token,
              error: "NewUserTokenError"
            }
          }
        }

        return {
          ...token,
          error: "InvalidProviderError"
        }
      }

      if (isJwtExpired(token.accessToken)) {
        return refreshAccessToken(token)
      } else {
        return token
      }
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken
      session.refreshToken = token.refreshToken
      session.error = token.error
      return session
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading `next-auth.js` to `4.7.0` with `next.js` at `12.2.0` fixed it for me.

Comment: Seems to be quite new indeed. This is also stated at: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware

Comment: I'm on next-auth 4.18.7 and nextjs at 13.1.1 but this problem still persist

Answer (score 3):

I'm using nextJS version 14 and next-auth 4.24 and found the same issue with next auth middleware. I'm using database strategies with next auth. For everyone who still figure out this issue. I manage it like this

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth({
  callbacks: {
    authorized: ({ req }) => {
      // verify token and return a boolean
      const sessionToken = req.cookies.get("next-auth.session-token");
      if (sessionToken) return true;
      else return false;
    },
  },
});

export const config = { matcher: ["/home/:path*"] };
```

The idea is to check if token cookies still exist, if it's not then redirect

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem and I was able to get it working correctly by disabled prefetching on the `<Link prefetch={false} href={'/protected-route'}/>` component associated with the protected pages in the application. I think that the prefetched version is cached and, upon successful singIn(), the cached version is served.
I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a different SECRET in .env (which was picked up by the middleware config), then the one that was set in [...nextauth].

Both must be the same. More info here https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#prerequisites